# Maximum of dependent binomial random variables.

Tags: probability, inequality, binomial-distribution

Suppose that I have 1 million balls ( $10^6$ ) and 1000 buckets. For each ball, I choose a bucket for it with equal probability. The task is to estimate the probability that some bucket contains more than 1250 balls, from the top.

If I define random variable $X_i$ as the number of balls in bucket $i$, then I have no idea how to estimate the maximal value of $X_i$ for $i$ from 1 to 1000 (or at least these which have more than 1250 balls in it), given just some information on just one of them.

Any hints on directions, or how to pick adequate random variables?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3406603/probability-of-more-than-k-balls-in-any-m-buckets-given-n-total-balls?rq=1

Comment: @d.k.o. this is certainly on topic, albeit not functional, as this is a problem to be solved on paper, and with 1000 buckets and 1000000 balls the inclusion-exclusion principle is cumbersome.

Comment: Then use an approximation (I gave one below).

Comment: Yes, this is helpful, but I need to read the paper you linked in detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The required probability,
$$
p\equiv\mathsf{P}\!\left(\max_{1\le i\le 1000}X_i>1250\right),
$$
is hard to compute directly. A possible approximation is given in [this paper](https://www.stat.purdue.edu/~dasgupta/mult.pdf). Specifically,
$$
\frac{\max_{1\le i\le 1000}X_i-1111}{\sqrt{500/(3\ln(10))}}+0.5\ln(4\pi)\overset{d}{\approx}\text{Gumbel}(0,0).
$$
Therefore, $p\approx e^{-e^{-17.6}}\approx 2.26\cdot10^{-8}$.